# Get column number information of multiple IDs in same line in antlr4 python target

Tags: python, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4, antlrworks

I am writing a  parser in python with antlr4.

In short, Input line is:

> *concept foo bar*

The grammar rule which parse above input line is:

```
start_rule: 'concept' identifier
identifier: ID {ID}
```

To get column number and line number of all IDs in input line I am adding code in enteridentifier(self, ctx) function.

```
enteridentifier(self, ctx):
    context = ctx.start
    line_number = context.line
    column_number = conext.column
```

The above snippet of code returns column number of first ID i.e. foo. If multiple IDs present in same line number (belongs to same rule) i.e. foo bar then how can I get column number for both IDs?

Comment: What is `{ID}`? If it's the second ID in a row, you probably want to use `identifier: ID ID?`

Comment: {ID} is zero or more occurrence. So identifier will be `identifier:ID` or `identifier: ID ID` or `identifier: ID ID ID`

Comment: @zigs, try this: `identifier: ID+`

Comment: ya tried. But not got expected column number info for other IDs

Answer (score 1):

On `enter` you will not have the entire (sub) parse tree ready for evaluation. Instead use the `exit` variant or (better yet) do a post-parse stage (often called the semantic phase) to extract this kind of information.

Once you have a complete (sub) tree, you can access the `ID` member in the `identifier` context, which is an array, if more than one occurences of a specific rule or token can appear. Iterate over that to get the individual child elements.

To get the column information for an `ID` use the fact that the for lexer tokens the `getChild()` call returns a `TerminalNode` instance (you have to cast the result to that). From there call `getSymbol()` which gives you a `Token` instance, which in turn has all the info for a specific token like text, channel, column, line, type etc.

Comment: I am able to get ID names by doing ctx.getChild(0).getText() , ctx.getChild(1).getText() etc. But unable to get appropriate column number information. Even though I evaluate in `exit` function I am unable to get column number info.

Comment: @ Mike Lischke: Yes, got it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad you solved it. Don't forget to accept my answer!